# Remap Bluetooth headset button on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, autohotkey

I have Bose QC 35 II and I am trying to get the Multifunction button to mute/unmute calls in MS Teams. For the purpose I will be using AutoHotKey, but in order to do that I need to capture the message this button is sending to Windows, so I can remap it to keyboard short cut. There is ready to use script here for the purpose: https://github.com/stajp/Teams_mute_AHK/

[image: MultiFunction button Bose QC 35 II]

The question is how can I capture the message it sends to Windows?

I have tried using AHKHID as described [here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/38015-ahkhid-an-ahk-implementation-).

**This script - Example 1** lists quite a few devices on my laptop:
[image: Example 1]

As I could not identify which Usage Page and Usage should use, I tried them all in Example 2, which is supposed to capture the key presses. I have added all combinations of Usage Page and Usage and after each I was pressing the Multi Function button of the headset to try to invoke a message being sent. But to no avail - no messages are being captured.

I also tried Usage Page 12 and Usage 1 with RIDEV_INPUTSINK, but this also did not trigger a message.

Is there is a more reliable way to validate if the headset is sending messages to Windows and what are they?

Comment: There is always the windows event log, in which every event that is thrown by a user, a service or something else is logged. With the windows “Task Scheduler” you can catch these events and use them for whatever you like. There are lists of which event number is what, you just need to find the particular event, probably “Audio Play” or something.

Comment: Would you provide information how to capture these events with Event Viewer? This is equal to capturing key down IMO and I am unaware how event viewer helps with it.